# C# Winforms and MySQL: Use "Number" or "Code" properties from MySqlException exception for show custom message in the form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

**[EDIT]:** When you have a *MySqlException*, you catch it; so the question is which property is for the MySQL error code, like:

- No connection to host (1042 err code)
- Timeout query
- Table no exists
- Duplicated Unique key, etc

So, which property from MySqlException get the error code: "Number" or "Code". With the value, I show custom message like icon change color and/or text in status bar

THANKS to [Bradley Grainger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23633/bradley-grainger) for answering and for have described the difference between both properties, Thank you very much.

Comment: You have tagged this C#, WinForms, and MySQL and included none of them in your question.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where you get the error message and also post the whole error mesege

Comment: Better if you include the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `MySqlException.Number` in your code when checking the error code.

- `MySqlException.Number` is the "original" error code property. It is an integer that can be cast to a [`MySqlErrorCode` enumeration value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlErrorCode.htm) to interpret the number.
- `MySqlException.Code` is a new property added in MySql.Data 8.0. It is for the new "X Protocol" and isn't used by regular connections to a MySQL database.

This isn't documented anywhere that I've found, but it can be seen in the code that [`Number` is set](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/3b8c67a21eda57eaecbef38d291fc7d026cd184e/MySQL.Data/src/MySqlStream.cs#L159) for the standard protocol, and [`Code` is set](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/3b8c67a21eda57eaecbef38d291fc7d026cd184e/MySQL.Data/src/X/Protocol/X/XProtocol.cs#L679) for the X Protocol.

If you use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), there's a strongly-typed [`MySqlException.ErrorCode`](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlexception/errorcode/) property that returns the error code as a `MySqlErrorCode` enum value, not an `int`.